# How to calculate inventory with past sales and purchases?

Tags: powerbi, dax, inventory

I have three tables in PowerBI, a sales table with articles sold over a year, the purchases of the articles within a year and the inventory at a certain timestamp.

I would now like to be able to calculate the inventory for every day.

The data could be exemplified like this:

[image]

I tried creating a column for every product and then 365 rows to show the inventory for every day. However, I do not know how to incorporate the inventory of 29.03.2019.

Also, for demonstration I only used three articles. If, however, I have a dataset of 10.000 products, what would be the ideal way to calculate this to be able to display it properly in a dashboard lateron?

Comment: Looks like you need to calculate the 'Starting' inventory amounts that are present before the earliest date in 'Sales' and 'Purchase'. For each article, subtract all purchases and add all sales that occur _before_ the inventory snapshot. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes I think that would work. I am just not sure if I should create a table with 365 rows and 3 columns (one per Article) and then calculate the inventory changes day by day. Or should I create a single table for each product which just lists the inventory changes day by day?.. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I created a StockTable where we have a purchase & sales combined:

```
StockTable = 
UNION(
    ADDCOLUMNS(Purch;"Event";"Purchage") ;
    SELECTCOLUMNS(Sold;"Article";Sold[Article];"PurchageDate";Sold[SalesDate];"Amount";-Sold[Amount];"Event";"Sold")
)
```

As we need to  ensure the relational model is correct, I added a new relation from Invent to StockTable 1:*
[image]

Next I added a column Stock on the StockTable, this calculates in relation to the inventory date of the article the stock on the specific date. It only has the records when a real change did happen (the 365 days is not needed).

```
Stock = 
var lastStockDate = RELATED(Invent[Date])
return if (StockTable[PurchageDate] < lastStockDate;
    RELATED(Invent[Amount in inventory]) + CALCULATE(SUM(StockTable[Amount]); FILTER(StockTable;StockTable[Article] = EARLIER(StockTable[Article]) && StockTable[PurchageDate] >= EARLIER(StockTable[PurchageDate]) && StockTable[PurchageDate] <= lastStockDate)) ;
    CALCULATE(SUM(StockTable[Amount]); FILTER(StockTable;StockTable[Article] = EARLIER(StockTable[Article]) && StockTable[PurchageDate] <= EARLIER(StockTable[PurchageDate]) && StockTable[PurchageDate] > lastStockDate)) + RELATED(Invent[Amount in inventory]))
```

Now it is possible to create a graph which shows the stock per article:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Aldert, this solution was exactly what I was looking for!